# Вывести ID записей из разных таблиц в одном JOIN запросе MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

имеется 2 таблицы c различными несвязанными ID.

Есть JOIN запрос:

```
"SELECT `f_data`.`id`, `f_data`.`prod_id`, `s_data`.`id`  from `f_data` join `s_data` on `f_data`.`prod_id`=`s_data`.`id`  WHERE `f_data`.`ok` is null LIMIT 1"
```

Как из этого запроса получить поле `ID` из каждой таблицы?

Таким запросом получаю только `ID` из первой таблицы

```
$tab_id = $q_info['id'];
```

Comment: какое `ID` вы хотите получить?

Comment: `f_data`.`id`,
`s_data`.`id`

Comment: Я вижу 3 ID `f_data.id`, `f_data.prod_id`, `s_data.id`, при этом судя по запросу `f_data.prod_id` == `s_data.id`, итого теоретически 2 разных ID может быть: `f_data.id` и `f_data.prod_id`. Я правильно все понял? Тогда получить: `$q_info['id']` `и $q_info['prod_id']` (а он в свою очередь равен `s_data.id`)

Comment: А, спасибо. Не догадался.
А, допустим, если у меня таблицы вида id | name  и id | name | last_name и связываются они полем name, можно получить id из первой и второй таблицы? Они же будут отличаться.

Comment: Да можно, второй ID автоматически переименуется в `id1`, третий дубликат переименуется в `id2`  и т.д. Чтобы такого не было можно самому в запросе указать имя используя `AS` например: `s_data.id AS 's_id'`, тогда, как вы уже догадались, будет `s_id`